# How to Fetch all user details from ldap using Ldaptemplate java spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

```
 public List<LdapUserDetails> findLdapUsers(String filter){
    List<LdapUserDetails> subUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean finished = true;
    int count = 0;
    do {try {
     subUsers = ldapTemplate.search(BASE_EU, filter, new PersonAttributesMapper());
         System.out.println(subUsers.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Catch Error "+e);
            if (e instanceof CommunicationException) {
                finished = false;
            }
        }
        if (!finished) {
            count++;
            if (count > MAX_RETRY) {
                finished = true;
            }
        }
    } while (!finished);
    return subUsers;
}
```

I am trying to fetch approx. 20k records from active directory but getting only 2500 records
LdapSearchfilter I have used (&(sAMAccountType=805306368)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=512)))

Comment: You should be able to get the rest using [Paged Search Results](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/processor.html#:~:text=5.3.%C2%A0Paged%20Search%20Results)